# sendmail sending mail to recipients I don’t know of; possible spam host

Tags: sendmail, spam, audit, malware

Recently I did an audit of my machine with logwatch and found out that my machine sends around 582 mails **everyday**.

```
 STATISTICS
 ----------

 Messages To Recipients:  582
 Addressed Recipients:    582
 Bytes Transferred:       444985
 Messages No Valid Rcpts: 0

 SMTP SESSION, MESSAGE, OR RECIPIENT ERRORS
 ------------------------------------------
```

Next day

```
 STATISTICS
 ----------

 Messages To Recipients:  153
 Addressed Recipients:    279
 Bytes Transferred:       8613451
 Messages No Valid Rcpts: 0

 SMTP SESSION, MESSAGE, OR RECIPIENT ERRORS
 ------------------------------------------
```

How can **I audit more to find out the email ids to where did is send, program which schedules this etc**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use log analyzer to find count of sender, recipient, domain etc. and other details. So that you can analyze the situation better.

Google Keyword: sendmail log analyzer

Answer (score 4):

You need to first fine out which MTA you are running. EXIM, Sendmail, Postfix etc.. Each of these MTA's have different log files. 
Without knowing your server setup, the best suggestion would be to dig into /var/log/maillog

Answer (score 3):

If you have syslog setup, there may be a /var/log/maillog file containing all the mail to/from lines.  I'm sorry that this will not indicate the program that sent the mail however.

Answer (score 1):

**Real** Postmaser **must** read **real logs**, everyday!

500+ emails per day isn't giant number for any mid-size e-mail emitter. Zero bounces is a (somehow) sign of "good nature" of these e-mails